# Browser-board-game and server push

Tags: javascript, events, php, server-push

I want to start developing a browser game. Not for success, just for the sake of doing it and learning something from it.

Now, a point where I have serious problems figuring out how to deal with it is; how does one player receive message of another player does something that is somehow time-critical.

Easy example for a trading card game; Player 1 plays `The devious flames of hell` and Player 2 has to react to this card by playing `Watery waves` directly afterwards, before the card of Player 1 takes effect (so to say a counter-card).

Of course, I could just request the server every second and see if the other player did something, but I was hoping for a less request-frequent solution, like the server pushes the event of Player 1 playing a card to Player 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lightwight cross browser library for server side push?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6524/lightwight-cross-browser-library-for-server-side-push)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just stumbled on this the other day -- check out NowJS at http://nowjs.com/ as I think it will give you a nice solution.

From the site...

> NowJS creates a magic namespace "now",
>   accessible by server and client. 
>   Functions and variables added to now
>   are automatically synced, in
>   real-time.  Call client functions from
>   the server and server functions from
>   client

Comment: Nice find. I wasn't even aware of Socket.IO.

Comment: Is that limited to the amount of simultaneous connections you can have at once?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use long polling in HTTP with Redis, if you want to reduce the pulling on the server. The script essentially "listens" for the "broadcast" from your script.

Answer (score 0):

"somehow time-critical" as in low latency?

WebSocket is the only way https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets

Answer (score 0):

Try [APE project](http://www.ape-project.org/)

It's great for low-latency server pushing